# WPF ui navigationview XAML binding failures with PaneDisplayMode="Top"

Tags: wpf, navigationview, c#-6.0

```xml
<ui:NavigationView
    x:Name="NavigationView"
    Grid.Row="1"
    EnableDebugMessages="True"
    Margin="10"
    IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
    IsPaneToggleVisible="False"
    BreadcrumbBar="{Binding ElementName=BreadcrumbBar}"
    MenuItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
    FooterMenuItemsSource="{Binding FooterMenuItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
    PaneDisplayMode="Top">
    <ui:NavigationView.Header>
        <StackPanel Margin="2">
            <ui:BreadcrumbBar x:Name="BreadcrumbBar" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ui:NavigationView.Header>
    <ui:NavigationView.ContentOverlay>
        <Grid>
            <ui:SnackbarPresenter x:Name="SnackbarPresenter" />
        </Grid>
    </ui:NavigationView.ContentOverlay>
</ui:NavigationView>

<ContentPresenter x:Name="RootContentDialog" Grid.Row="0" />
```

When I set `PaneDisplayMode="Top"`, I received warning:

[image: Image: XAML binding failures]

> Popup.PlacementTarget, Name='SubMenuPopup'
> Cannot find source: ElementName=Border.

So, what cause this happened and how to fix it?

I tried but couldn't find any information about this error, when I set `PaneDisplayMode=Left/Bottom` this error does not occur.